# Using a Subject to trigger a Subscription in an Angular App when required

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I am not sure if I am going around this the right way. But I have a component in my Angular app, that when initializing will call an API service for data and then I will use this data. I want the API call to happen again and again when triggered by an event, it could be a button click for example. To be more efficient with my code I am trying to trigger the API call subscription by using a Subject and the `repeatWhen` RxJS operator. Here is my code.

```
export class MyNiceComponent implements OnInit {

    issues$ = new Subscription();

    issueSubject$ = new Subject<any>();

    selectedFilters: any = {};

    constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.issues$ = this.apiService.getIssues();
        this.issues$.pipe(repeatWhen(this.issueSubject$))
            .subscribe((issues: any) => {
                console.log('Boom! I have been triggered');
                // Do Something with issues and complaints
            });
    }

    updateFilters(selectedFilters: any): Promise<void> {
        console.log('yes, updateFilters') 
        this.selectedFilters = { ...selectedFilters };
        // trigger the this.issues$.subscribe();
        this.issueSubject$.next();
    }
}
```

As you can see I have my `updateFilters` method. When this is called I use the `next()` method of the `issueSubject$` to run `repeatWhen(this.issueSubject$)` part of my `issues$` subscription. However the API call is only ran once on the ngInit lifecycle, even though the `updateFilters()` method is being called. What am I doing wrong here? Am I confused in my implementation? If I have asked this question badly please let me know and I will rewrite this.

Comment: You define `issues$ = new Subscription();` but the use `pipe` against it like here `this.issues$.pipe(...)`. What type of object is `issues$`? A Subscription or an Observable? Then, coming yo your question, why don't you call `this.apiService.getIssues()` any time you need it, at init time and at the occurrence of the events (e.g. a button clicked)?

Comment: I am not sure which rxjs version you are using but repeatWhen takes a function as argument. So it would look like this with your code: `repeatWhen(() => this.issueSubject$)`

Answer (score 0):

You can just simplify , like it

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   
  issueSubject$ = new Subject<any>();
  selectedFilters: any = {};

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

  loadData() {
    this.apiService.getIssues().subscribe(response => {
        // TOD with Server Response 
    })
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.issueSubject$.subscribe(response => {
      this.loadData();
    })
    this.issueSubject$.next(null);
  }

  updateFilters(selectedFilters: any): any {
    console.log('yes, updateFilters');
    this.selectedFilters = { ...selectedFilters };
    // trigger the this.issues$.subscribe();
    this.issueSubject$.next(null);
  }

  
}
```